# PolyBase create an external table to query Hadoop, column count mismatch

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, polybase

We have run a polybase service to query on our hadoop cluster.
Here is the file structure in our hadoop side:

> Structure for /warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/xxxxxxx/dxxxxxx/created_month=2019-11/base_0000083/bucket_00001
> File Version: 0.12 with ORC_135
> Rows: 51107
> Compression: ZLIB
> Compression size: 262144
> id:int,
> xxx
> xxx
> xxx

**There are 16 fields in this side**

On the other side, I have created a file format as follows:

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT [OrcFileFormat] WITH (
    FORMAT_TYPE = ORC,
     DATA_COMPRESSION = N'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec')
```

and the external table as below:

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[test]
    (
        id:int,
    xxx
    xxx
    xxx
    )
    WITH (DATA_SOURCE = [hadoop_test],
    LOCATION = N'//warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/xxxxxxx/dxxxxxx/created_month=2019- 
     11/base_0000083/bucket_00001'
    ,FILE_FORMAT = [OrcFileFormat]
    ,REJECT_TYPE = VALUE,
    REJECT_VALUE = 500)
```

With exactly copied fields and the only change to data types were string to varchar and timestamp to datetime.
The table is created successfully; however, when following query is executed:

```
     SELECT TOP (1000) *
      FROM [dbo].test
```

This error is thrown:

> Cannot execute the query "Remote Query" against OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "(null)". External file access failed due to internal error: 'File //warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/xxxxxxx/dxxxxxx/created_month=2019-11/base_0000083/bucket_00001: HdfsBridge::CreateRecordReader - Unexpected error encountered creating the record reader: HadoopExecutionException: Column count mismatch. Source file has 6 columns, external table definition has 16 columns.'

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurs when ORC is created as a transaction table. In this situation, ORC files contain some other information like operation, etc. If you open your ORC file, it'll look like as the following format:

`(operation, originalTransaction, bucket, rowId, currentTransaction, (ActualData))`

where ActualData is your actual data that have been stored in the file. So, as you can see, it seems you have 6 columns against your actual columns count. As Microsoft has said about Polybase limitations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-versioned-feature-summary?view=sql-server-ver15#known-limitations), you will not be able to read ORC transaction files.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer but a step in troubleshooting. Try creating the external table with a dummy field, i.e. dummy int, and run the query. When it fails due to a column mismatch, it tells you what fields were found along with their collation. This can help you troubleshoot further.